# Android Studio Import Dependencies

Tags: android-studio

I had to re-install Android Studio 2.1.3 and now i have some errors. Some of my imports are missing e.g.

```
 android.os.Handler;
 google.gson.Gson;
 android.util.Log;
```

How do install these libraries? I tried File=>project Structure=>app=>depenencies and did a search for google.gson.Gson was there but studio is not loading it. The other libraries were not listed in dependencies. Where can I load those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your using Android Studio as admin otherwise upating gradle will fail.
This answer helped me.

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555135/the-best-way-to-integrate-third-              party-   library-in-android-studio
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add android.os.Handler and android.util.Log in your dependencies.if you have allready add Gson api as

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

just build your project the classes will be automatically import,if not then go to your source code and line which are shown in red hit alt+enter and import classes.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working import android.util.Log; is still red -as is the reset. Is there a way to rest the project and import these libraries?

Comment: would u plz check sdk path at Tool>>Android>>SDK Manager and at path specify in ur project at File>>Project Structure>>Sdk Path,both are must be same if not then set your sdk path as SDK Manager path at File>>Project Structure>>Sdk