# How to add third party SDK in android studio

Tags: android

I want to add third party sdk in my android project.
Can anyone tell me the process step by step....
I tried but can't...
My Process:

1. Copy and paste jar file in libs folder
2. Add dependency in build.gradle file
3. then clean the project and build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to integrate third party library in Android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555135/the-best-way-to-integrate-third-party-library-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below methods :

First method:

1. switch your folder structure from Android to Project.-> paste the .jar file inside libs folder->Right click on the jar file and at end click on Add as library->This will take care of adding compile files('libs/library_name.jar') in build.gradle after sync gradle -> make sure compile files('libs/library_name.jar') added your build.gradle file -> Then build your project

Second method:

2.(If 1st method does not work for you then try it.)
switch your folder structure from Android to Project.-> paste the .jar file inside libs folder->Select Dependencies Tab, add the file by using + .Click on file dependency and Select your jar file from libs directory.->Then click OK->This will take care of adding compile files('libs/library_name.jar') in build.gradle after sync gradle -> make sure compile files('libs/library_name.jar') added your build.gradle file -> Then build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android SDK Manager. At the tools tab selecct Manage Add-on Site. Then go to the User Defined Sites tab and click new. A the prompt dialog enter the URL you wish to add. Then close the window. Back at the Android SDK Manager scroll down and u should be able to locate the SDK u added. If needed at the packages tab of the SDK Manager click Show Archive Details