# How to use SDK to call function?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have a third party program software which is written in android. When this app generates alarms I have to write these an alarms on db. They send me to their SDK's. How can I use them SDK and get alarms to write db ? I dont know how to do it, any kind of help is really appreciated. Thank you very much.

## What I have tried;

I copy SDK's on `app->libs` folder
In `AndroidManifest.xml` file I add stated permission which provided by SDK's documentation.

And also they provide some codes. However where I should write these codes and how to call them there is no information.

What can I do ? How can I progress ? How can use this app sdk in my project ? Is there a way or any kind of tutorial ? I cannot provide code because of the policy of company.

Comment: Provide some more details what you want to do.

Comment: What kind of details should I provide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export that SDK to jar file and include in your libs folder then add as library to call in your application.

Tutorial [app to jar](https://youtu.be/1i4I-Nph-Cw), similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934555/how-to-add-third-party-sdk-in-android-studio#39936879).