# flutter embedded pos printer (Like: Android Q2 device)

Tags: flutter, posprinter

Already I have built a flutter project. Now I need to print from a pos embedded device. I am googling, but I don't get any solution.

Please help me if there is any solution.

Actually I need for **Android Q2 device**

[image: Android Q2 device]

Comment: did you resolved this problem?

Comment: @MichaelMendoza, no I couldn't Because it was earlier 2018 model sdk. which cannot be added directly. So I write custom function to add this sdk. But it takes time to print

Comment: Can you get solution for this issue? I can't also printing with flutter app that embedded on device. That mean printing not work forever and sometime get output. But can print from emulator.

Comment: @LaPyae Q2 device version is not compatible which I was used. I update the device and use company provided android sdk nd called the print from the flutter code.

Comment: Yes ... I also contact company and they fix with local ip REST API.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

In your case, you can download the SDK provided by the company and write native code to print the receipt.

example:

in flutter

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('com.example.myapplication');

Future<void> _print() async {
    try {
        final bool result = await platform.invokeMethod('print',{"data":Printdata});
        if (result) {
            // success
        } else {
            // failed
        }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        //failed to print
    }
}
```

Then in the `Main.java` / `Main.kt` implement the method from the SDK documentation

example:

```
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("print")) {
        data = call.argument("data");
        // Code from SDK documentation
    } else {
        result.notImplemented();
    }
}
```

ref: [Example Nativcode in flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab)

[Add third party SDK to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934555/how-to-add-third-party-sdk-in-android-studio)

Comment: no. this package is bluetooth/wifi or usb depended. But embedded printer device is direct connect. I think it is not work for this solution.

Comment: does it comes with android SDK ?

Comment: for more information I add device image. I don't know how it's work.

Comment: can you at least share what company and model number it is. if you have any documentation share it too.

Comment: Model: (POS-Q2) Android Portable POS Terminal with 58mm thermal Printer
OS: Android 6.0
RFID: 13.56MHZ 14443A NFC (HF)

Comment: This package worked for me: https://github.com/kakzaki/blue_thermal_printer Connects to the built-in printer using Bluetooth.

Basic code sample available here: https://github.com/kakzaki/blue_thermal_printer/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device and i already built flutter application , and ran into the same probleme .
I contacted the company and they provided me with android sdk so i added a channel and called the print from the flutter code.

Comment: Hi. @mohannad youssef thanks for your guideline. when I call the channel it no longer works. can I get any sample source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library "flutter_bluetooth_serial" and connect to the printer via direct mac address like this:

BluetoothConnection connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress("mac");